# Leaflet Wikipedia layer

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to use the Wikipedia layer in english:
http://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/Leaflet.Wikipedia.js

but I'm not successful on using the leaflet infotips "BindPopup".
The code could be working with a sidebar, but I prefer infotips.
Can you correct the line for me please?

[image]

```
function onMoveEnd(evt) {

  var template = '<h2>{label}</h2><p><img src="{thumbnail}"><br>{abstract}</p><p><a href="{link}">Read on Wikipedia</a></p>';

  L.wikipedia({
    query: {
      fields: ['label', 'lat', 'lng', 'abstract', 'link', 'thumbnail'],
      bounds: map.getBounds()
    },
    marker: {
      icon: L.icon({ // Icons from http://www.icondrawer.com/social-icons.php
        iconUrl: 'https://mappingforyou.eu/icons2/wikipedia_16.png',
        iconRetinaUrl: 'https://mappingforyou.eu/icons2/wikipedia_32.png',
        iconSize: [16, 16]
      })
    }
  }).addTo(map).on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.layer.bindPopup((template), {maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200});



  });
}

map.on('moveend', onMoveEnd);
```

Comment: Is this linked to leaflet data providers plugin to display Wikipedia API entries on a map layer? I have been having trouble getting that to work properly.

Comment: @WombatBill look here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421181/hide-wikipedia-plugin-layer-below-certain-zoom-level-in-leaflet?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the

```
      evt.layer.bindPopup((template), {maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200});
```

was replaced with

```
      evt.layer.bindPopup(L.Util.template(template, evt.layer.data), {maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200});
```

as in

```
function onMoveEnd(evt) {

  var template = '<h2>{label}</h2><p><img src="{thumbnail}"><br>{abstract}</p><p><a href="{link}">Read on Wikipedia</a></p>';

  L.wikipedia({
    query: {
      fields: ['label', 'lat', 'lng', 'abstract', 'link', 'thumbnail'],
      bounds: map.getBounds()
    },
    marker: {
      icon: L.icon({ // Icons from http://www.icondrawer.com/social-icons.php
        iconUrl: 'https://mappingforyou.eu/icons2/wikipedia_16.png',
        iconRetinaUrl: 'https://mappingforyou.eu/icons2/wikipedia_32.png',
        iconSize: [16, 16]
      })
    }
  }).addTo(map).on('click', function (evt) {
          evt.layer.bindPopup(L.Util.template(template, evt.layer.data), {maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200});


  });
}

map.on('moveend', onMoveEnd);
```

and successfully managed to show the data.

[image]