# Hide Wikipedia plugin layer below certain zoom level in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, zoom, leaflet-plugins

How can I turn the following code into a variable, so that I can choose, or not, to load it in the layer control?
and not anymore on moving the map or reaching this zoom level.

I added a `var wikilayer =` before "function on moveend" and brackets here and at the very end, but it's resulting in the browser minding on the ending bracket and the page not to function from this code

Following is a working code  with the following js file found at  Github from Turban's repositery
https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Wikipedia

```
// wikipedia 

var start_at_zoom_wiki = 10;

function onMoveEnd(evt) {
  if (map.getZoom() > start_at_zoom_wiki) {

    var template = '<h2>{label}</h2><p><img src="{thumbnail}" width="150"><br>{abstract}</p><p><a href="{link}" target="_blank">Wikipedia...</a></p>';

    L.wikipedia({
      query: {
        fields: ['label', 'lat', 'lng', 'abstract', 'link', 'thumbnail'],
        bounds: map.getBounds()
      },
      marker: {
        icon: L.icon({ // Icons from http://www.icondrawer.com/social-icons.php 
          iconUrl: 'http://mappingforyou.eu/icons/wikipedia_16.png',
          iconRetinaUrl: 'http://mappingforyou.eu/icons/wikipedia_32.png',
          iconSize: [16, 16]
        })
      }
    }).addTo(map).on('click', function (evt) {
      evt.layer.bindPopup(L.Util.template(template, evt.layer.data), customOptions);
    });
  }
}

map.on('moveend', onMoveEnd);
```

and this is my alternate layer control from [here](https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-panel-layers/src/leaflet-panel-layers.js)

```
var baseLayers = [];
var overLayers = [{
  group: " ",
  layers: [{
    active: false,
    name: "Wikipedia (test)",
    icon: '<i class="icon icon-restaurant"></i>',
    layer: wiki,
  }, ]
}, ];

// panel

var panelLayers = new L.Control.PanelLayers(baseLayers, overLayers, {
  compact: true,
  collapsed: true,
  collapsibleGroups: false
});


map.addControl(panelLayers);
```

Comment: I changed my text and I tried to put everything in a variable, at the moment... @TomazicM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Leaflet.Wikipedia` plugin has a big defficiency/bug that it does not refresh data when map is zoomed or panned. This means that on any map zoom/pan, which triggers map `moveend` event, layer has to be recreated.

Simplest way to do this is to have an auxiliray layer group `wikipedia`, where old data/features is first cleared out and then new data/features are added.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var map = L.map('map');
map.setView([51.4235064, -1.7134741999999998], 13);

var osmLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var template = '<h2>{label}</h2><p><img src="{thumbnail}" width="150"><br>{abstract}</p><p><a href="{link}" target="_blank">Wikipedia...</a></p>';

var wikipedia = L.layerGroup();

function getWikipadeaData() {
  var newWiki = L.wikipedia({
    query: {
      fields: ['label', 'lat', 'lng', 'abstract', 'link', 'thumbnail'],
      bounds: map.getBounds()
    },
    marker: {
      icon: L.icon({ // Icons from http://www.icondrawer.com/social-icons.php 
        iconUrl: 'http://mappingforyou.eu/icons/wikipedia_16.png',
        iconRetinaUrl: 'http://mappingforyou.eu/icons/wikipedia_32.png',
        iconSize: [16, 16]
      })
    }
  }).on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.layer.bindPopup(L.Util.template(template, evt.layer.data), customOptions);
  });
  wikipedia.clearLayers();
  wikipedia.addLayer(newWiki);
  if (!map.hasLayer(wikipedia)) map.addLayer(wikipedia);
}

var baseLayers = [];       
var overLayers = [
  {
    name: "Wikipedia",
    icon: '<img src="http://mappingforyou.eu/icons/wikipedia_16.png">',
    layer: wikipedia
  },
];

var panelLayers = new L.Control.PanelLayers(baseLayers, overLayers);
map.addControl(panelLayers);

var start_at_zoom_wiki = 10;
function onMoveEnd(evt) {
  if (map.getZoom() > start_at_zoom_wiki) {
    getWikipadeaData();
  }
}
map.on('moveend', onMoveEnd);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the zoom worked, what I want to do is toggle on/off these wikipedia items in the control layer. At this moment, the wikipedia items are loading by moving a bit the map but I have no control on them beside zooming out to unallow further loads and those loaded would'nt disappear. And I need to preserve the onMove function

I'm sorry I didn't link the correct Wikipedia script here it is: http://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/Leaflet.Wikipedia.js

Comment: it is the javascript from Turban https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Wikipedia

Comment: What do you mean by "control layer"? Is it "layer control"? There is no layer control in your code, see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers

Comment: yes, layer control, but I have an alternate layer control, I will include its text

Comment: See modified answer.

Comment: thanks. I made a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/01dgcwrL/1/ but I'm quite not successful ..

Comment: It is loading in the initial zoomed area but not If I move the map http://mappingforyou.eu/test/ I put in this page this important code I forgave
    var customOptions =     { maxHeight: 200, maxWidth: 200   };

Comment: Only now I realized this plugin has a big/defficinecy that it does not refresh features when map is zoomed or panned. See modified answer.

Comment: Thank you Tomazic, the code looks better now. It only requires to define var customOptions = { maxHeight: 200, maxWidth: 200 };  and it works.  But I'd like to let the user the choice to run wikipedia in the layer control, he can only remove the layer . and on panning and zooming , items would come again. I'd give up the 'startatzoom' for that @TomazicM . Thank you for helping me with that.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly now: you want user to turn Wikipedia layer on/off in layer control any time, regardless of zoom level?

Comment: yes... zoom levels are deepening the problem. In large cities, there would be too much info at a large scale, but the user could just turn off the layer. it would make things easier.. and I would like it to be off by default... and off until it's triggered in the menu

Comment: Then please edit your question and describe desired behavior for Wikipedia layer.

Comment: Thanks, I had difficulties to   understand the logic between layergroups and layers as I was a beginner, but now I understand better.. a lot of months were required.. thank you for your patience with me !!

Answer (score 1):

This is how the plugin works if you want to use a button to show the articles, but still prevent to load articles when using a low zoom factor.

Maybe there is an easier way than using a variable like state=1 or state=0, but at least it works. The fact is, I didn't tried to add it to a Leaflet layer control.

this leaflet wikipedia articles plugin could be edited by using https in the dbpedia calls, choosing the language, choosing the maximum articles on a map.

```
// implementing early variables


var temoinwiki;
var wikipedia = L.layerGroup();
var start_at_zoom_wiki = 9
var template = '<p>{label}</p><p><img src="{thumbnail}" width="150"><br>{abstract}</p><p><a href="{link}" target="_blank">Wikipedia...</a></p>';

// get the wikipedia info

function getWikipediaData() {
    var newWiki = L.wikipedia({
    query: {
        fields: ['label', 'lat', 'lng', 'abstract', 'link', 'thumbnail'],
        bounds: map.getBounds()
    },
    marker: {
        icon: L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'https://mappingforyou.eu/icons2/wikipedia_16.png',
            iconRetinaUrl: 'https://mappingforyou.eu/icons2/wikipedia_16.png',
            iconSize: [16, 16]
        })
    }
}).on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.layer.bindPopup(L.Util.template(template, evt.layer.data), {
        maxHeight: 200,
        maxWidth: 200
    });
});


wikipedia.clearLayers();
          wikipedia.addLayer(newWiki);
if (!map.hasLayer(wikipedia)) map.addLayer(wikipedia);
            }           ;

// changes data when moving panning or zooming the map

function onMoveEndwiki(evt) {
  if (map.getZoom() > start_at_zoom_wiki && temoinwiki === 1) {
    getWikipediaData(); }

    else if (map.getZoom() <= start_at_zoom_wiki) {wikipedia.clearLayers()};
};

map.on('moveend', onMoveEndwiki);

// button, requires leaflet easybutton

var wikibtn = L.easyButton({
    states: [{

      stateName: 'loadwiki',        // name the state
    icon:      '<strong>W</strong>',               // and define its properties
    title:     'Wikipedia articles',      // like its title
    onClick: function(btn, map) {       // and its callback 
        temoinwiki = 1;
         if (map.getZoom() > start_at_zoom_wiki) {getWikipediaData()};   
        btn.state('removewiki');    // change state on click!
    }
}, {
    stateName: 'removewiki',
    icon:      '<strong>W*</strong>',
    title:     'Remove Wikipedia articles',
    onClick: function(btn, map) {
temoinwiki = 0;
map.removeLayer(controlMarkerwiki);
         wikipedia.clearLayers();
        btn.state('loadwiki');
    }
}]
});

wikibtn.addTo(map);
```